# Show that $\left| \oint_{\partial D}fdx + gdy \right|^2 \leq (\text{Area}(D))\int_D \left( |\nabla f|^2 + |\nabla g|^2 \right) dx dy.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\vec{F}=(f,g):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth vector
>   field such that $|\vec{F}(x,y)|\to 0$ rapidly as $|(x,y)|\to \infty$,
>   and let $D$ denote a compact domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose boundary
>   $\gamma$ is a smooth non-self-intersecting closed curve in
>   $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $$\left\vert  \oint_{\gamma}\left(f\,{\rm d}x + g\,{\rm d}y\right) \right\vert^{2}
>  \leq \left(\text{Area}\left(D\right)\right)\int_D
> \left(\left\vert\nabla f\right\vert^{2} + \left\vert\nabla g\right\vert^{2} \right)\,
> {\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y.$$

I start out by noting that $$\oint_{\gamma}fdx + gdy = \int_D (g_x - f_y) \,dx dy.$$

The $\text{Area}(D)$ part is crying out for me to use Cauchy-Schwarz, in the form $$|\langle \varphi,1\rangle_{L^2(D)}|^2 \leq \|\varphi\|^2_{L^2(D)}\|1\|^2_{L^2(D)}=\text{Area(D)} \|\varphi\|^2_{L^2(D)}$$ for some function $\varphi$.

Now $$\left(\int_D(g_x-f_y)\,dxdy\right)^2\leq \left(\int_D|g_x-f_y|\,dxdy\right)^2\\[19pt] = \left|\langle g_x-f_y,1\rangle_{L^2(D)}\right|^2$$

and now it would remain to show that $$\int_{D}(g_x-f_y)^2 dx dy \leq \int_{D}f_x^2 + f_y^2 + g_x^2 + g_y^2\,dx dy,$$ but I don't think that is always true.

Also I have not used the decay of $\vec{F}$...but I don't see how that's relevant, since $D$ is compact.

Any ideas?