# Definition of $\oint_{\gamma}\left(f\,{\rm d}x + g\,{\rm d}y\right)$

Tags: notation, definition, contour-integration

Let $\vec{F}=(f,g):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth vector
 field and let
 $\gamma$ be a smooth non-self-intersecting closed curve in
 $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> I would like to know what is the definition of the following expression:
>   $$\oint_{\gamma}\left(f\,{\rm d}x + g\,{\rm d}y\right)$$

found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625320/show-that-left-oint-partial-dfdx-gdy-right2-leq-textaread-in) question. Similar expressions appear [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620499/oint-gamma-frac-yx2y2dx-fracxx2y2dy-over-two-different-paths), or in the statement of Green's theorem.
I don't understand how we can integrate $f$ only w.r.t. $x$, for instance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical definition is
$$\int_{\gamma}(f\,\mathrm{d}x+ g\,\mathrm{d}y) = \int_{a}^{b}\vec{F}(\gamma(t))\cdot\dot{\gamma}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,$$
where $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and the dot above the $\gamma$ denotes (component-wise) differentiation.

The idea is that the integrand is $\vec{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\gamma$ by abuse of notation and the chain rule, and then writing $\mathrm{d}\gamma = (\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y)$ gives the notation in question.